# WCF Client fails with authentication error after host service restart

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have two WCF services on remote machines. Service A is hosted via IIS, Service B is self-hosted. Binding is set to basicHTTPBinding and no authentication is required. Service A calls Service B and passes some encrypted data. Both services communicate fine.

Then Service A is restarted (while B is still running). Service A now gets a "The caller was not authenticated by the service." error message when trying to communicate with Service B. Restarting service B has no impact. But, stop service B, wait 15-20 minutes and restart, it works. Meanwhile, service A communicates the whole time with another self-hosted service C, without issue, even after restarting Service A. Service A and C are same service just on different machines. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Have you tried using [WCF diagnostics](http://petarvucetin.me/blog/2013/02/setting-wcf-diagnostics-quickly/)?

Comment: Yes, we used the diagnostics. The problem was related to configured timeout differences. Once we set the timeouts to all the same values  the problem stopped.